# Need help validating Europa bank note can't get it to validate properly, unsure of why

Tags: javascript, html, validation, currency

My validation (see below) for the new Europa bank notes did not work. This is the rule:

> It needs to first get the length of the note, convert the first two
>   letters into numbers, and finally add the remaining numbers together.
>   If the number mod by 9 returns 0, it should return true.

If anyone could help me, that would be great. Thanks.

```js
function formValidationCheck() {

  var europaValue = document.form.eurbank.value; //takes value entered
  var europaVal1 = europaValue.charCodeAt(0); // get's the first letter
  var letter1 = europaVal1 - 65;
  var europaVal2 = europaValue.charCodeAt(1);
  var letter2 = europaVal2 - 65;
  var numbers = euuropaValue.substring(3, 12);
  var total = letter1 + letter2 + numbers; // adds total of both letters and numbers
  var tcheck = total % 9; // mods total by 9


  if (europaValue.length > 12) // checks length
 {
    document.getElementById('eurbank').style.background = 'pink';
    document.getElementById('eurbank').style.border = "solid red 2px";
    alert("Bank note number must be less than twleve charaters!");
    return false;
  }


  if (tcheck != 0) //checks the total
 {
    document.getElementById('eurbank').style.background = 'pink';
    document.getElementById('eurbank').style.border = "solid red 2px";
    alert("That is an invalid europa bank note.");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="formValidationCheck();" method="get">
  Full name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="fullname">
  <br>Phone number:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phoneNum" required>
  <br>Email:
  <br>
  <input type="email" name="email" required>
  <br>Credit Card Type:
  <br>
  <select name="credit card type">
    <option value="visa">Visa</option>
    <option value="master">Mastercard</option>
  </select>
  <br>Credit Card Number:
  <br>
  <input type='text' name='creditnum' id='creditnum' required>
  <br>Europa Banknote number:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name='eurbank' id='eurbank' required>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Purchase Now" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: are u getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No it won't put out any errors no matter what you type in, it just accepts whatever you enter into it.

Comment: `var total = letter1 + letter2 + numbers;` This is not going to add the numbers together, this is just going to perform string concatenation.

Comment: Could you tell me how I could add them together please?

Answer (score 0):

Try parse the letter into integer before doing the numerical operation.

```
var total = parseInt(letter1) + parseInt(letter2) + numbers;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it seems to be more than just that that's wrong unfortunately.

Comment: add alert(letter1) and so on along the way to debug. Otherwise, it is more useful to show us the error log from the browser console